# SQL request with multiple joins condition on a list of transactions (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, nested

I have a transactions table with a this structure of data, showing the most important fields to keep in mind.
It's a list of transactions, where type=1 transactions are account deposit, while type=2 are account withdrawals.

```
login | type | value | date.     
1234  |   1  | 100   | 25/09/2021
1234. |   2. | 250.  | 26/09/2021
4321. |   2. | 234.  | 13/09/2021
4321. |   1. | 342.  | 14/08/2021
...
...
```

What I'm trying to get is the list of the accounts, where their balance during the period is bigger than > some amount, X, and no active deposits after 16/09/2021.

```
SELECT  t.date, 
a.login, t.account, sum(d.value) as deposits, sum(w.value)  as withdrawals,  sum(d.value) - sum(w.value) as balance
FROM b.transactions AS t 
    INNER JOIN b.accounts as a ON t.account=a.id
    INNER JOIN b.transactions AS d ON t.account = d.account and d.date=t.date and d.type=t.type
    INNER JOIN b.transactions AS w ON t.account = w.account and w.date=t.date and w.type=t.type
WHERE 
d.value - w.value > 5000 and 
d.type = '1' and 
w.type = '2' and 
d.date<='2021-09-29' and d.date>='2021-09-29' and
w.date<='2021-09-29' and w.date>='2021-09-29' and 
t.date<='2021-09-29' and t.date>='2021-09-29' and 
t.account not in 
(
SELECT  t.account
FROM b.transactions AS t 
where t.type  in (1) and 
t.date>='2021-09-16' and 
t.value>0
group by t.account

)
```

I'm getting some output, but it looks like seriously underestimated (at least 10x- fold)... Can not find the mistake, where should I look?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: "...their balance during the period is bigger..." - do you mean the balance is **always** bigger than X, or just **at least once** (and then it could be lower)?

Comment: I mean their cumulative balance during the whole long period of time (now it's one day only, but the intention is to have it from January to yesterday this year), so the sum of the deposits - sum of the withdrawals > some X cumulatively..

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this — I don't think it is necessary to join the same table three times:

```
SELECT t.date, 
       a.login,
       t.account,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.type = '1'
                THEN t.value
                WHEN t.type = '2'
                THEN -t.value
           END) AS balance
FROM b.transactions AS t 
    INNER JOIN b.accounts AS a
        ON t.account = a.id
WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2021-09-29' AND '2021-09-29' 
GROUP BY t.account
HAVING sum(CASE WHEN t.type = '1'
                THEN t.value
                WHEN t.type = '2'
                THEN -t.value
           END) > 5000;
```

Comment: Laurenz, thanks a lot! Keeping in mind that I have other types of the transactions in the table, beyond 1 and 2, and I need to keep in mind only 1 and 2, I think the cases should be like:
CASE 
WHEN t.type = '1' THEN t.value 
WHEN t.type='2' then -t.value
           END

right?

Comment: I adapted the answer. Now other transaction types are not counted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Laurenz!
Works like a charm!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

First, to compute the running balance you can use a window function. For example:

```
select
  login, date, type, value,
  sum(
    case when type = 1 then value when type = 2 then -value end
  ) over(partition by login order by date) as running_balance
from t
order by login, date;
```

Result:

```
 login  date                      type  value  running_balance 
 ------ ------------------------- ----- ------ --------------- 
 1234   2021-09-25T00:00:00.000Z  1     100    100             
 1234   2021-09-26T00:00:00.000Z  2     250    -150            
 4321   2021-09-13T00:00:00.000Z  2     234    -234            
 4321   2021-09-14T00:00:00.000Z  1     342    108
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle - Simple Running Balance](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vb8m4kG2RH6WzQjPKaBC9U/0).

Then you can use the logic above to compute more complex values so you can use them to filter data, as in:

```
select distinct login
from (
  select
    login, date, type, value,
    sum(
      case when type = 1 then value when type = 2 then -value end
    ) over(partition by login order by date) as running_balance,
    sum(
      case when type = 1 and date > date '2021-09-16' then 1 else 0 end
    ) over(partition by login order by date) as extra_deposits
  from t
) x
where running_balance >= 100 and extra_deposits = 0
```

Result:

```
login
-----
4321
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle - Full Query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vb8m4kG2RH6WzQjPKaBC9U/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, The Impaler!